# How to get different fonts for SH1106 OLED LCD?

Tags: lcd

I've got a SH1106 1.3" OLED LCD working fine with the [luma driver](https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.oled) (on I2C) and using the default font on a Pi Zero W running bullseye. I'd just like to use a larger font, but cannot figure out how! How do I specify a larger size for the default font? I installed the [luma examples](https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.examples), and `welcome.py` shows some other fonts that I'd like to use, but how do I specify these fonts in my own code?

Comment: potentially helpful (not sure, I didn't use such fancy packages): [Drawing multilingual text using PIL and saving as 1-bit and 8-bit bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47545359/3904031) and [Are there vintage or historical bitmapped fonts available for non-commercial use?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8627/7118)